# change a software version through registry editor

Tags: drivers, windows-registry, nvidia-graphics-card, version

i was wondering that can we change the version of a software through registry editor or something like that.

i actually installed a game (need for speed) that was asking for a particular driver version (of nvidia) 322.xx but i was having 300.xx

So can we change somewhere software version to fool the game.

Comment: Can't you just install the newer driver? After all if the software requires it, it might not work with older versions anyway.

Comment: This entirely depends on the software in question?  Have you tried changing the registry key to see if it works?  Its very likely the registry is NOT used in a case like this, the driver version is very likely an API call, and one of the first checks software like `Need for Speed` would make to insure compatability with the system.  **In other words update your Nvidia drivers.**

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, messing with registries is always a messy business. Different programs store all sorts of data in weird and wonderful filing structures. You would have to research where this certain data is stored.

More importantly, if a game (or any other software) is asking for a certain driver, it's probably because it needs it. The developers are unlikely to limit the user for no reason.

Besides, up to date drivers are usually a good thing.